# How can i filter my firebase database and add them to my android spinner?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

So i have this family database and i want a spinner that list of curvillage and filter them not to repeat cuz many people will have same curvillage.

Tell me how to show spinner for all curvillage. 
after this i want to make a new page where display all people from same curvillag i selected.

```
Spinner spinner;
DatabaseReference databaseReference;
ValueEventListener listener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        listener=databaseReference.child("family").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                final List<String> family=new ArrayList<String>();
                for(DataSnapshot familySnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    String familyname=familySnapshot.child("curvillage").getValue(String.class);
                }

                Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.dataspinner);
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, family);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
}
```

}

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following to remove duplicated curvillages, that you could then use to display a list of.

```
const uniqueCurvillage = [...new Set(family.map(f => {
   return f.curvillage
}))];
```

Comment: can you tell me how to add curvillage values in spinner